# Echo in headphone after soldering

Tags: soldering, headphones

I am not an electrical engineer, but because I broke the 3.5mm jack of my headphone, I decided to mod it to have a removable cable.

It's a headphone with mic (HyperX Cloud2).
It works well when I plug a 3 conductor audio cable into it (left and right speakers working properly.)

The issue is when I use a 4 conductor audio cable, the sound becomes really weird, kind of echoish.

I wonder what the cause could be.

- Did I solder wires on wrong pins?
- Are some cables still insulated?

How could I test this to know where this issue is coming from?

Comment: Ah..the Cloud2. Them 3.5mm cables are always broken. xD Echo in an earphone denotes a bad ground. Can you show pictures or details of your mod? I'm not sure exactly how you modded it. I think you reversed the ground and Mic pins though.

Comment: Did you wire it like this? https://i.imgur.com/WrlzIUC.png  If you reversed the Mic and GND locations, you will have your issue.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I' ll try to revert the mic and gnd cables tonight. (I'll also add photos so It will be easier to understand)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Natsu Kage was right.

I inverted the microphone wire with a ground wire.

Here is how it looks after the fix:

[image]

(Yes, it looks really dirty but well, I had a lot of troubles.)

I had swapped the white and red wires.

Comment: I've done this error multiple times myself when I first started repairing headsets like the Cloud2, haha.  You might want to add the picture I gave earlier in the comments to your answer, to help others.

Comment: Keep in mind that this convention is not consistent between manufacturers.  Moving forward, there is a tendency to put mic on shell and ground on ring2, but it's not consistent in legacy devices.

Answer (score -1):

What i did?
Mine has:

- Red(mic)
- gold (ground)
- blue
- green
- red+blue

I soldered the dual colored wire(red+blue) with either blue  or green wire.
I thought the dual color wire was ground.
Everything worked.